# Extract colors from image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a black and white image and the same image with color strokes. What I want to do is extract the color strokes, blur them and then blend original with the blurred image. I extract the color strokes by subtracting two images from each other, but I get those color strokes on a black background, whereas I need them on white to blend with the original. This is part of my code:

```
def imageblur(cimg):
    return cv2.blur(cimg, (50, 50))


bw = glob('path1')
colorful = glob('path2')
output_dir = 'path3'
index = 0


for i,j in zip(bw, colorful):
    img1 = cv2.imread(i)
    img2 = cv2.imread(j)
    color = cv2.subtract(img1,img2)
    color = imageblur(color)
    mask = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(color))
    img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img1))
    im = Image.blend(img, mask, 0.5)
    #color = img1 + color
    im.save(os.path.join(output_dir, str(index) + '.jpg'))
    index += 1
    print(index)
```

Sample [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbvBb.jpg)

Comment: what did you expect to happen? 255 (white) - 255 (white) = 0 (black). any own ideas or do you just want to be spoon-fed a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna change the background from black to white for RGB images, you can do something like this :

```
#thresholds all black color in your "color-on-black-background" image 
#to maximum value (255,255,255) (white) and sets the rest (yours colors) 
#to (0,0,0) (black)
thresholded=cv2.inRange(img,(0,0,0),(0,0,0))
#add both images
res=img+cv2.cvtColor(thresholded,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Input (img) : [image]

Thresholded (thresholded) :  [image]

Output (res) : [image]

Answer (score 3):

To extract colors from image:

```
import colorgram

# It is the number of colors you want to extract from the image
nb_colors = 30      

# Returns a list of tuples form (r, g, b) 
image_colors = colorgram.extract("image.jpg", nb_colors)
```

Answer (score 2):

Used the sample image to get the result. The processing is slightly changed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

def show(title, img, color=True):
    if color:
        plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1]), plt.title(title), plt.show()
    else:
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray'), plt.title(title), plt.show()

img = cv2.imread('color_strokes.jpg')
show('original', img)

mask=cv2.inRange(img,(0,0,0),(150,150,150))
show('mask', mask, False)

res=255-cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
show('result', res, False)
```

Output:

[image: color_strokes_output]

Answer (score 1):

```
image = plt.imread('image.jpg')

# Extract 2-D arrays of the RGB channels: red, blue, green
red, blue, green = image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]
```